# How to listen for changes in the input choice set of an adaptive card?

Tags: javascript, node.js, botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I have been making a teams bot using Bot framework sdk 4.0 and Node JS.
i have this adaptive card with an image and input selection choices as a drop down and selecting and clicking the update button (which is an action.submit button) will update the image in the adaptive card.
[image]

I want to make it so that instead of having to click the update button i want it to trigger the update function when the selection is made from the dropdown list.

How do i listen for the selection in the dropdown list in the bot?

Comment: Currently, there is no event triggered by input in Input.ChoiceSet. When a choice from the ChoiceSet is selected, there is no event sent to the bot
 
To achieve your requirements, we recommend you give your feedback in Teams Feedback Portal.

Answer (score 0):

To listen for changes in the input choice set of an Adaptive Card in your Teams bot, you can use the app.adaptiveCards.actionSubmit method to handle the action.submit event triggered by the dropdown selection.
Register the Adaptive Card action handler in your bot code using the app.adaptiveCards property. This will listen for the action.submit event triggered by the dropdown selection.

```
app.adaptiveCards.actionSubmit('DynamicSubmit', async (context, _state, data: SubmitData) => {
  // Handle the dropdown selection here
  await context.sendActivity(`Dynamically selected option is: ${data.choiceSelect}`);
});
```

In your Adaptive Card JSON, make sure to set the id property of the action.submit button to match the action name specified in the code above (DynamicSubmit in this example).

```
{
  "type": "Action.Submit",
  "title": "Update",
  "id": "DynamicSubmit"
}
```

if you want to update the image in the Adaptive Card based on the selected option, you can modify the action handler code as follows:

```
app.adaptiveCards.actionSubmit('DynamicSubmit', async (context, _state, data: SubmitData) => {
  // Update the image based on the selected option
  if (data.choiceSelect === 'Option 1') {
    // Update image for Option 1
  } else if (data.choiceSelect === 'Option 2') {
    // Update image for Option 2
  } else {
    // Handle other options
  }
  await context.sendActivity(`Dynamically selected option is: ${data.choiceSelect}`);
});
```

Refer : [Microsoft Teams AI GitHub repository](https://github.com/microsoft/teams-ai/tree/main/js/samples/03.adaptiveCards.a.typeAheadBot) Specifically, you can refer to the [index.ts file](https://github.com/microsoft/teams-ai/blob/main/js/samples/03.adaptiveCards.a.typeAheadBot/src/index.ts#L92) for the implementation details.

Comment: Instead of using the button i want to remove the button and use the selection from the drop down to trigger the changes

Answer (score 0):

you can use onInput property and add handler to it
example :

```
// Create an Adaptive Card with an Input.ChoiceSet
const card = {
  type: 'AdaptiveCard',
  body: [
    {
      type: 'Input.ChoiceSet',
      id: 'myChoiceSet',
      choices: [
        { title: 'Option 1', value: 'option1' },
        { title: 'Option 2', value: 'option2' },
        { title: 'Option 3', value: 'option3' }
      ],
      onInput: handleChoiceSetInput // Specify the callback function
    }
  ],
  actions: []
};
// Function to handle the choice set input
function handleChoiceSetInput(event) {
  const selectedValue = event.value;
  console.log(`Selected value: ${selectedValue}`);
  // Perform any desired actions based on the selected value
}
// Send the Adaptive Card to the user
await context.sendActivity({
  attachments: [CardFactory.adaptiveCard(card)]
});
```

Comment: This is not working for me, it does nothing when i select the values i the input choice set.
you're calling the handleChoiceSetInput with an argument but the declaration for the function has an argument.

Comment: Here we are attaching a handler to the onInput property , we are  not calling it.When an event occurs ,it gets called automatically

Comment: ok, but the function is not triggering when i change the selection in the adaptive card.

Comment: Hello user9262680 - We cannot bypass the button click event and post the data to backend bot because once you click on the button, a event will be triggered and captured by bot and later we can fetch the data from turn context and save it.

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft i want to avoid that button click and trigger the event when the user selects the choice from the input choice set itself.
if it is not possible in this way, what would u suggest for me to make a dynamic chart like this displayed in the teams bot framework?

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft ,  can you please help me?